# How to get to total count instead of individual count from column with Having clause on another column when using select subqueries in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table named **'billingpatencounter'**, that looks like the below table -

| mrno | patencounterid |
| --- | --- |
| N23 | 38 |
| N23 | 39 |
| N23 | 40 |

The mrno are not distinct.

I want to count the total number of **mrno** where the **patencounterid** are > min(patencounterid).

From the table we can see the min(patencounterid) is 38 and the answer should be **2** as there are two mrno (with patencounteid as 39 & 40) who have patencounterid > min(patencounterid).

**Result I am getting -**

| count |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 1 |

I am using **PostgreSQL** and I tried the below code -

```
SELECT   COUNT(mrno)
FROM     billingpatencounter
WHERE    mrno = 'N23'
GROUP BY patencounterid
HAVING   patencounterid > (SELECT MIN(patencounterid)
                           FROM   billingpatencounter
                           WHERE  mrno = 'N23');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WHERE cannot use aggregation. But you can use the result of a subquery for comparison. I added two lines with 'N22' for clarity.

```
CREATE TABLE billingpatencounter(
        mrno TEXT,
        patencounterid INT
);

INSERT INTO billingpatencounter(mrno, patencounterid) VALUES    
 ('N23', 38),
 ('N23', 39),
 ('N22', 38),
 ('N22', 39),
 ('N23', 40)
;

SELECT * FROM billingpatencounter;
```

Output

```
 mrno | patencounterid
------+----------------
 N23  |             38
 N23  |             39
 N22  |             38
 N22  |             39
 N23  |             40
```

And you need to group by the `mrno` column. Since `patencounterid` you have all different values and this will lead to the fact that the aggregation will be on `each row`. I removed the grouping in the request, since it is not needed here. The request itself:

```
SELECT   COUNT(patencounterid)
FROM     billingpatencounter
WHERE    mrno = 'N23' AND patencounterid > (SELECT MIN(patencounterid)
FROM   billingpatencounter
WHERE  mrno = 'N23'
) 
;
```

Output

```
 count
-------
     2
```

Comment: And as far as I know, HAVING is used to filter already aggregated data.